# Maximum and Supremum of Intervals

Tags: real-analysis

The following intervals are these maximum and supremum correct?  If not what am I going about wrong with these since the max is the largest value in the set and the sup is the least upper bound:
`[x,y] Max: y Sup: y
(x,y) Max: y-1 Sup: y
[x,y) Max: y-1 Sup: y
(x,y] Max: y Sup: y
(-inf, y] Max: y Sup: y
(-inf, y) Max: y-1 Sup: y
[x, inf) Max: None  Sup: None
(x, inf) Max:None  Sup: None
(inf, inf) Max: None  Sup: None`

Comment: Why would the maximum value in the interval $(0,2.5)$ equal $1.5$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if maximum exists then it equals to the supremum. Many of your answers are wrong. For example, why do you think $y-1$ is the maximum of $(x,y)$? Assuming $x<y-1$ the point $y-\frac{1}{2}$ also belongs to this set, as well as $y-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Actually any real number $z$ which satisfies $x<z<y$ is in this set. So $y$ is indeed the supremum of this set while a maximum just does not exist. For any number which is smaller than $y$ you can always find a bigger number which is still smaller than $y$-try to prove that. And then try to fix your answers for the other exercises.

I'll add just a few words about sets like $(x,\infty)$. It definitely has no maximum, while the supremum is up to definitions. Some say $\infty$ is the supremum, others say the set has no supremum. It depends how you define it.